# How can I stop Jquery Validator validating each field automatically?

Tags: jquery, validation

I only want to validate the elements on a form when I save the form. So I call this directly. Is there a way I can stop the validator validating each filed as its changed.

Thanks 
Scott

Comment: which validator plugin are you using ?

Comment: Your question is bad. You are asking how you can stop validator validating each field, but by default there is no validation, and there is many validation plugins from which you are using one. It is like asking "How do I send a SMS?" without providing phone model. For us that don't have crystal bowl :), you should answer JMax's question, 4 users upvoted it because they wanted to answer you, and they could not because you did not have asked your question in a way that can be answered.

Comment: I assume it's [this one](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [this validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation), then this should do the trick:

```
$(".selector").validate({
   onfocusout: false
});
```

This tells the valididation plugin to not validate on focusout. There are [a bunch of options](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options) that you can pass to the plugin to get it to behave differently.